# How to align a node vertical to one node and horizontal to another node?

Tags: tikz-pgf

Is it possible to align node c vertical to node a and horizontal to node b. If I combine the "below=of" and "right=of" parameter, Tikz ignores the first one.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[draw, circle, xshift=2cm](a){A};
  \node[draw, circle, minimum width=2cm, yshift=-2cm](b){B};
  \node[draw, below=of a, right=of b](c){C};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: You can use `\node[draw](c) at (a|- b){C};` instead.

Comment: @percusse Let me return the favour: perhaps you could convert your comment to an answer.

Answer (score 16):

You can use the orthogonal identifiers `|-` and `-|` for intersections of different coordinates. A quick reading hint is go vertical  `|` and then horizontal `-` or vice versa.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[draw, circle, xshift=2cm](a){A};
  \node[draw, circle, minimum width=2cm, yshift=-2cm](b){B};
  \node[draw](c) at (a|- b){C};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks!  It can also be helpful to assign an anchor, like     `\node[anchor=south] (c) at (a -| b.south) {C};` to get control over further specifics of positioning relative to the existing nodes.